# RPATH failed to let native app find shared library on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I build a native executable, that runs inference using gpu delegation. This executable relies on the `libtensorflowlite_gpu_delegate.so` that I copied to the same directory. However, when I run it, I got error saying that this shared lib is not found, so apparently, I need to set the `RPATH` to `./`, and the executable is able to find this shared lib.

But then I ran into another error saying: "libOpenCL.so not found". I found this shared lib in `/system/vendor/lib64`, so I copied it to the same directory, and everything works.

However, I dont want to duplicate this shared lib if system already have it, so I add `RPATH` of `/system/vendor/lib64` to my executable, and I confirmed with `readelf`:

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x9fc0058 contains 40 entries:
  Tag                Type                 Name/Value
 0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/system/vendor/lib64/:./]
```

However, with this new `RPATH`, I still get error saying "libOpenCL.so not found". Not sure if that is access constrain, but I am under `adb shell` with `su` enabled. and that file has accesibility of `-rw-r--r--`

My question is:

1. why setting `RPATH` here does not work?
2. I feel this may not be the best way to let my native app to find the native libs under system folder, I have another non-native app that can use GPU delegate. I read docs saying `any native shared library is accessible regardless of whether it is an NDK library` at least for the API_LEVEL I have. So I just wonder if there is away to add access for natively built apps?

Answer (score 0):

Because apps are not allowed to access vendor libraries: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.md#private-api-enforced-for-api-level-24

Comment: well, i am using api_level 21,  so it shouldn't be affected according to the link, right?

Comment: Your minSdkVersion is irrelevant. The API level of the device is what matters. If you're running on an Android 5.0 device (API 21), the restriction does not apply, but RPATH isn't implemented for devices that old so it still won't work.